# Excel VBA Find a row in another sheet, then change a cell in the same row

Tags: vba, excel

I know there are lots of questions like this, but i couldn't get any of them to work for me.
Basically i'm putting a print button on PRINT sheet.
When clicked i would like to take the order number (which is on the PRINT sheet),
find it on ORDERS sheet then put a text like ,"printed" to another column in the same row of that order.
I've solved the printing part no problems there.
But couldn't get any of the codes to work. I'm a newb. please consider it with your answers :)

```
  Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim lrow As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheets("SPRS"): Set ws2 = Sheets("ETÝKET")


        Set aCell = ws1.Columns(1).Find(What:="26182-2" _
                , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SPRS").Range(aCell).Value = "printed"


End Sub
```

Comment: Would be easier if you gave the code for your best attempt and said why it was not working for you.

Comment: look into the Range.Find and the Offset functions.

Comment: `Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim lrow As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheets("SPRS"): Set ws2 = Sheets("ETÝKET")

    
        Set aCell = ws1.Columns(1).Find(What:="26182-2" _
                , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SPRS").Range(aCell).Value = "printed"
 
    
End Sub`
@ScottCraner here is the code

Comment: This line `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SPRS").Range(aCell).Value = "printed"` change to `aCell.Offset(,1).value = "Printed"`  Where the Offset(,1) is the next column to the right.  Change the 1 to the number of columns to the right desired.

Comment: the code gives and error now, i don't know why
Error 1004
Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 0):

In the click buttons function for print add something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ORDERS").Range($row).Value = "printed"
```

Where $row is the cell you want that presumably would correspond to the PRINT sheet.